# Why are default values specified in 2 places for React Context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Looking at the current [`useContext()` docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext), it seems we can specify default or initial values for context in two places:

1. Once in the createContext()
2. Or when we specify `<MyContext.Provider value={value}>`, the `value` at the end of line is the initial values

(example of [initial value for #1 is in this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-usecontext-hook/), while for #2, it is in the docs mentioned in the beginning. Or even in that docs, they may do it at both places:

```js
const ThemeContext = createContext('light');  // ONCE HERE, but some example use `null`

export default function MyApp() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>  // AND THERE HERE AGAIN, theme is 'light'
```

)

So I am not sure why there can two places and which one should be use?

Answer (score 0):

createContext returns a context object. Components can read your context by passing it to useContext(), and "value" is one or many of your states inside your useContex.